# Mailchimp - Gmail converts words containing periods to links

Tags: gmail, mailchimp

1. I'm designing a newsletter in Mailchimp for an organization named "co.sempre.tu"
2. I mention the project name in some paragraphs blocks along the newsletter and after an email test sent to different email providers, I realized that only Gmail formats (converts) the project name as if it was a link.
3. Is there a workaround for this Gmail idiotic behavior? I tried replacing the period (.) with its HTML Number equivalent (`&#46;`) and although it works in Mailchimp text editor, somehow along the way it reformats back to text and voilá, links again... :(